# Rename namespace prefixes with XQuery (Update)

Tags: xml, xquery, xml-namespaces

The following problem can easily be solved with text processing tools and languages, but this is not how it should be done I guess..

What’s the cleanest and cheapest approach to rename namespace prefixes in a large XML document with XQuery (Update)?

**Source:**

```
<a:root xmlns:a="http://my.old.url/"/>
  <a:sub/>
</a:root>
```

**The result I’d like to get:**

```
<b:root xmlns:b="http://my.old.url/"/>
  <b:sub/>
</b:root>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XQuery Update

In XQuery Update you can use the [`rename`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-rename) expression to rename all elements in a given namespace:

```
declare namespace ns='http://my.old.url/';
for $nd in doc('your-db')//ns:*
return rename node $nd as QName('http://my.old.url/', concat('b:', local-name($nd)))
```

If you don't want the changes to be permanent, you can wrap the updates in a [*Transform Expression*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-transform), too:

```
declare namespace ns='http://my.old.url/';
copy $doc :=
  document{
    <a:root xmlns:a="http://my.old.url/">
      <a:sub/>
    </a:root>
  }
modify
  for $nd in $doc//ns:*
  return rename node $nd as QName('http://my.old.url/', concat('b:', local-name($nd)))
return $doc
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to remove the old "a" prefix declaration from the result?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to do in XSLT, but in XQuery I think you would just essentially do the same thing. Declare the namespace prefix you want, then recursively process the nodes and update the element names to use that prefix.

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace b="http://my.old.url/";

declare function local:update-ns-prefix($node)
{
  typeswitch($node)    
    case element() return 
      element { xs:QName(concat('b:',local-name($node))) }
      {
        $node/@*, 
        for $n in $node/node()
        return local:update-ns-prefix($n)
      }
    default return $node
};

let $xml :=
<a:root xmlns:a="http://my.old.url/">
  <a:sub xmlns:a="http://my.old.url/"/>
</a:root>
return local:update-ns-prefix($xml)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any solution available that takes less memory? I noticed that the recursive approach fails for larger documents with several mega or giga bytes. Next, your query assumes that you used MarkLogic for processing your query. What about replacing namespace prefixes in existing database documents?

Comment: @HannesBauer I forgot to remove the ML version, but this should work in any XQuery compliant processor. However, I can't think of a simple alternative that uses less memory (functx has an XQuery function that does something similar, and it also processes recursively). The only thing I can think of would be a batch process that accepts some nodes and updates them non-recursively. Then spin off jobs in individual transactions sequentially. This assumes the documents are in the db, and you have some method of updating nodes.

Comment: I decided to vote for Leo's solution as it comes closer to what I was looking for.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @HannesBauer If you had specified what database you were using I could have offered a solution. Not all XQuery databases support XQuery Update.